# b.jgrid.formatter error for clearGridData and reloadGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datagrid, jqgrid

I'm making an ajax call to my controller, the data will be after that show in a grid with a pager in it.this is my grid declaration.

```
function BuildApportGrid() {
jQuery("#grid_apport").jqGrid('GridUnload');
jQuery("#grid_apport").jqGrid({
    editurl: "clientArray",
    datatype: "json",
    data: [],
    colNames: ['Code Barrage', 'Organisation', 'Nom', 'Date', 'Cote à 8h', 'Volume total', 'Debit', 'Apport', 'Volume restitue'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'code',
        index: 'code',
        hidden: true,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }, {
        name: 'organisation',
        index: 'organisation',
        hidden: true,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }, {
        name: 'nom',
        index: 'nom',
        hidden: false,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }, {
        name: 'date',
        width: 100,
        index: 'date',
        hidden: false,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }, {
        name: 'cote_a_8h',
        width: 100,
        index: 'cote_a_8h',
        hidden: false,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }, {
        name: 'volume_total',
        width: 100,
        index: 'volume_total',
        hidden: false,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }, {
        name: 'debit',
        width: 100,
        index: 'debit',
        hidden: false,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }, {
        name: 'apport',
        width: 100,
        index: 'apport',
        hidden: false,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }, {
        name: 'volume_restitue',
        width: 100,
        index: 'volume_restitue',
        hidden: false,
        search: false,
        editable: true
    }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {},
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {},
    onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) { },
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: false,
    pager: '#pager_grid_apport'
});

jQuery("#grid_apport").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager_grid_apport', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refresh: false
}).navButtonAdd('#pager_grid_apport', {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-excel",
    title: "Exporter vers excel",
    onClickButton: function () {},
    position: "last"
}).navButtonAdd('#pager_grid_apport', {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-linechart",
    title: "Verifier les bornes sur la carte",
    onClickButton: function () {},
    position: "last"
});
```

the html part look like this :

```
<div class="content_div" style="margin-left:5px">
  <table id="grid_apport"></table><div id="pager_grid_apport"></div>
```

the ajax call is the following:

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '/xxx_web/Prelevement/getGridData',
             dataType: "json",
             data: {
                 date_debut: dijit.byId('start_date_apport').get("value"),
                 date_fin: dijit.byId('end_date_apport').get("value"),
                 selxml: viewerFrame.mapFrame.GetSelectionXML()
             },
             success: function (data) {
                 jQuery("#grid_apport").jqGrid("clearGridData");//erreur
                 jQuery("#grid_apport").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                     datatype: 'local',
                     data: data
                 }).trigger("reloadGrid");

             }
         });
```

the error show is : TypeError: b.jgrid.formatter is undefined.
when I comment this line the grid work but doesn't clear data when I reload data. what i'm missing ?! thanks for your time.
this is more details for this weird error having for the grid :

- in the above cases, the error block the execution and no data will be
  load on the grid.
- if I delete the pager part from the grid : pager:
  '#pager_grid_apport' the data load normally without problems,but i
  need the pager in my grid so this is not the solution.
- if i remove the line jQuery("#grid_apport").jqGrid("clearGridData");
  from the ajax call, the data will be load to the grid but the same
  error appears.

what i'm missing ?!

**EDIT :**

data is a json format,this is the json construction:

```
var jsonData = 
(from item in data select new { 
code = item[1] == null ? "" : item[1].ToString(),
organisation = item[2] == null ? "" : item[2].ToString(),
nom = item[3] == null ? "" : item[3].ToString(),
date = item[4] == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item[4]),
cote_a_8h = item[5] == null ? "" : item[5].ToString(),
volume_total = item[6] == null ? "" : item[6].ToString(),
debit = item[7] == null ? "" : item[7].ToString(),
apport = item[8] == null ? "" : item[8].ToString(),
volume_restitue = item[9] == null ? "" : item[9].ToString()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Which format has the items of the `data` array which you use? Could you include 2 items of test data? Has the items unique `id` property or some other property, which is native id of the items on the backend (`/xxx_web/Prelevement/getGridData`)?

Comment: thank you @Oleg for replaying, i am using jqGrid  4.4.1